# Connection String error while using ADOMD.NET to connect to Azure Analysis

Tags: azure, adomd.net, azure-analysis-services

I am trying to retrieve data from Azure Analysis Services using ADOMD.NET from a deployed model in cloud. The code snippet is as below, but i am getting an error that the ConnectionString in invalid.

```
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test_Analysis_Service_retrieval
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string queryString = @"SELECT [MAP_CUST_NAME] FROM [AAS_MAPLOOKUP] where [MAP_ACT_NO] = '120000810';";
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=asazure://westus.asazure.windows.net/bbacloud;UserName=xyz@gmail.com;Password=ABC@123;";

            using (AdomdConnection connection = new AdomdConnection(connectionString))
            {
                CellSet AASOutput = null;
                System.Xml.XmlReader reader = null;
                try
                {
                    string s = connection.ConnectionString;
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                    connection.Open();
                    AdomdCommand command = new AdomdCommand(queryString, connection);
                    command.CommandTimeout = 100000;
                    reader = command.ExecuteXmlReader();
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadOuterXml());
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (reader != null)
                    {
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you need to do is to ensure you have the latest ADOMD.NET (AdomdClient) installed. Download it from [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=829577). After you have installed it, then make sure your C# project has a reference to it at:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient\v4.0_13.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll`

Next, you need to change your connection string to:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=asazure://westus.asazure.windows.net/bbacloud;User ID=user@domain.com;Password=pwdHere;Initial Catalog=DatabaseNameHere";
```

Note a few things. First, it's User ID not UserName. Second, the user needs to be an Azure Active Directory user (an organizational account, not a personal LiveID). Finally, you need to specify the Initial Catalog to ensure that you connect to the correct database in case you ever have multiple databases deployed.

**Update**: The latest is available on Nuget for [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.retail.amd64/). Or if you are building a .NET Core app use [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.NetCore.retail.amd64/).

Comment: This was the first time I saw a path to the dll file going into Windows instead of Program Files and I was finally able to connect to Power BI!

Comment: @halfofaglazier I updated the answer with a link to Nuget which has the absolute latest. Highly recommended for connecting to Power BI

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this issue is due to the RTM version of AdomdClient not actually supporting the RTM version of Azure Analysis Services.  As a result, the following Nuget Package is required:

https://github.com/ogaudefroy/Unofficial.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient

Once you remove / uninstall the version 12 ( the RTM version ) of Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.12.0.2000.8 and install the above AdomdClient everything works just fine.  In short, the v12 version doesn't have the code built in to parse asazure:// Data Sources

Highly annoying with no documentation on Microsoft's site nor support relating to the problem.  However this will address your question.

Comment: Use the official nuget package please https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.retail.amd64/