# AdomdConnectionException was unhandled - The connection string is not valid

Tags: c#, adomd.net

```
     public static void connect()
     {   
        try
        {
            string connectionStringStaging = @"Data Source=<server_name>;Catalog=<catalog_name>;User ID=<user_name>;Password=<my_password>";
            string commandText = @"SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[# Opptys moved to Committed] } ON COLUMNS FROM [Model] 
                                    CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS";
            AdomdConnection connection = new AdomdConnection(connectionStringStaging);
            connection.Open();
            AdomdCommand cmd = new AdomdCommand(commandText);
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (AdomdConnectionException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error : " + ex.ToString());
        }
     }
```

I am using the above code to connect to server and then I am further running MDX queries using this.The problem is the error I am getting - "The connection string is not valid" at line

```
connection.open();
```

Are the settings name incorrect which I am using in my connection string?Can someone help me figure out what is wrong in my connection string ?

The stack trace is as follows:
[image]

Comment: Can you try with `User ID` (with space) instead of `UserName`?

Comment: I have tried using     `User ID`     also but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44896064/6456290). The unofficial package worked just fine . So I installed the reference `Unofficial.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient` and so the problem was not in the connection string but in the package.

Comment: Glad to know that you figured it out. Please mark your answer as a solution.

Comment: @BogdanAnghel Yes I will mark my answer but I can do that only after 24 hours after I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please consult the following documentation from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.adomdconnection.connectionstring.aspx

You can also find some examples of connection strings here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/adomd-net/

Hope this will help you sort the problem.

Comment: I have already seen the same document but nothing helps, I am not able to find what is wrong in my connection string

Comment: Please enclose the code in a try / catch block and post the full stack trace here so I can better understand the problem.

Comment: From what I can see in the stack trace the `connection.Open()` call needs to parse a port number, that is not provided in the connection string. 
Your problem may be in the <server_name> string. Below are the examples from the Microsoft documentation:
1.Data source=AW-SRV01 for the default instance and port (TCP 2383).
2.Data source=AW-SRV01$Finance:8081 for a named instance ($Finance) and fixed port.
3. Data source=AW-SRV01.corp.Adventure-Works.com for a fully qualified domain name, assuming the default instance and port.
4 Data source=172.16.254.1 for an IP address of the server.

Comment: My Data Source is `Data Source=asazure://aspaaseastus2.asazure.windows.net/dwraasstaging`

Comment: The link you gave didn't work but the answer below it fixed my issue.